# execute multiple quires at once in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I need to execute 3 quires when user comes to main page.

```
 public function index()
{
    $slider = \App\Slider::select("title", "poster", "link", "sub_title")->translate()->orderBy("created_at", "asc")->get();
    $services = \App\Page::getPage(24)->tabs()->translate()->get();
    $partners = \App\Partner::select('id', 'title', 'link')->translate()->get();

    return view('Front/index', compact('slider', 'services', 'partners'));
}
```

as you can see, I need to get images from slider, take page data and take some company partners info. so i execute 3 quires to get what i want. is there way to make only one query and union all these 3 quires in one? I want something like `multi_query` function in php. no matter it would be in eloquent or query builder.
p.s. I don't eloquent relationships, these data aren't related to each other

Comment: "I want something like multi_query function in PHP..." No, you don't, you really don't. That thing has destroyed companies and ruined careers because it can't be secured.

Comment: What's the problem here? This should run three queries and return the results in the variables you've specified. Why would you want to union these all together? Do they perform adequately? If one of them is slow, creating a `UNION` will only make them slower and running a `multi_query`, even if such a thing were possible or advisable, would not magically make things faster.

Comment: @tadman would't be better in this situation to running one union query, instead of 3?

Comment: No, nothing about this warrants a `UNION`. Why are you so hung up on this? What's the problem here?

Comment: If there's a really important reason that you absolutely HAVE to fetch all of this at once, I would suggest e.g. creating a view to fetch it from if able instead. But I agree with @tadman completely. Edit: although on second hand, it looks like you probably can't do that either.

Comment: If this is a performance problem and the source data doesn't change very frequently you *might* want to pull the pin on caching, but I'd be very cautious before doing that because it's often frustrating to get caching implemented correctly. Most pages on a modern app will make 15-20 database calls, it's honestly no big deal.

Comment: ok guys, thank you for some good advise

Answer (score 1):

just put ur query inside `$qry=DB::select("your_query");`

```
 return view('your_view',compact('qry'));
```

you can see following also  for better unterstand

```
$emp_id="5623";
$var_start_date=$request->startdate;


$data_query= DB::select("SELECT  orinfo.*,
                                 chinfo.name as chname

            FROM order_info orinfo, ch_info chinfo
            WHERE orinfo.ch_id= chinfo.ch_id 
            AND orinfo.emp_id= ? 
            AND
            to_char(orinfo.order_Date,'mm/dd/yyyy') BETWEEN ? AND ? order by orinfo.order_Date desc",[$emp_id,$var_start_date,$var_end_date]);
```