# How to add bracket in laravel query builder using 'WHEN' condition?

Tags: php, laravel

Given this code:

```
$objResellerList - DB::table('ResellerMaster as RM')
  ->leftJoin('StateMaster as SM','SM.id',RM.id_StateMaster')
  ->leftJoin('RegionMaster as REM','REM.id','=','RM.id_RegionMaster')
  ->leftJoin('DealerGroupMaster as DGM','DGM.id','=','RM.id_DealerGroupMaster')
  ->when($keywords, function($query) use ($keywords) {
    return $query->where('RM.company_name', 'like', '%'.$keywords.'%')
      ->orWhere('DGM.name', 'like', '%'.$keywords.'%')
      ->orWhere('RM.email', 'like', '%'.$keywords.'%')
      ->orWhere('RM.pic', 'like', '%'.$keywords.'%')
      ->orWhere('RM.pic_mobile_no', 'like', '%'.$keywords.'%');
  })
  ->when($status, function($query) use ($status) {
    return $query->where('RM.status', $status);
  })
  ->select('RM.*','SM.name as state','REM.name as region', 'DGM.name as dealer_group')
  ->orderby('RM.company_name','asc')
  ->paginate(10);
```

When i search with keywords, I need to close it with a bracket at when condition. How to include the bracket at when condition?

Comment: Kindly attach your code instead of an image.

Comment: Please share your code, So i change your code

Comment: Need bracket to cover the keywords part, before come to where condition in status, how to do that?

Comment: you can use DB::select("your_query"); http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40696230/execute-multiple-quires-at-once-in-laravel/40700407#40700407

Comment: I want to use 'when' because, user might not type anything to search. If use DB::select, cant check my status or keywords got input value or not

Comment: Converted image to code

Answer (score 0):

```
 DB::table('users')
        ->where('name', '=', 'John')
        ->orWhere(function ($query) {
            $query->where('votes', '>', 100)
                  ->where('title', '<>', 'Admin');
        })
        ->get();
```

give u brackets

select * from users where name = 'John' or (votes > 100 and title <> 'Admin')

so use where with function

```
->orWhere(function ($query) {
            $query->where('votes', '>', 100)
                  ->where('title', '<>', 'Admin');
        })
```

or

```
->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('votes', '>', 100)
                  ->where('title', '<>', 'Admin');
        })
```

it will give u brackets

use

```
->when($status,function($query) {
   return $query->where(function ($query) {
        //do some action
    })
})
```

Comment: ->when($status, function($query) use ($status) {
                           return $query->where(function($query) use ($status) {
                                return $query->where('RM.status', $status);
                            });
                        })                                                                                                              I write like this but no effect.